# Fixing my responsive HTML and CSS landing page

Tags: html, css

i'm completely a newby and clueless about coding, i tried building this landing page similar to that one that is demonstrated on this YouTube video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYWitDwHhxE) with VSC.

For some reason i've got it wrong and there are a few problems:

1. The headline, first paragraph(a sentence) and the menu are all at the top of the page instead of one above the other.
2. The main paragraph is going downwards instead of going from left to right as shown in the video.
   3.The background picture is missing and the profile picture should be underneath the main paragraph.
3. I can't get the logic of how making the pag responsive with the different CSS functions.

Here is the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

section{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: url(bg.jpg)no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

header{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header .navigation{
color: #000;
background: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 2px 15px;
border-radius: 20px;
transition: 0.3a;
transition-property: background;
} 

header .navigation a:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 30px;
}

header .navigation a:hover{
    background: #fff;

}

.content{
    max-width: 65px;
    margin: 60px 100px;
}

.content .info h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content .info p{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.media-icons{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.media-icons a{
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.media-icons a:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.media-icons a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35552f1379.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>My Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
    </head>
<body dir="ltr">
    <section>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <header>
            <h2 style="color: white;"><span>Welcome, I'm Boaz Kaplan</span></h2><br>
            <p style="color: white;"><span>Thanks for visiting my website!</span></p><br>
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <a href="#">My Linkedin Page</a>
            </div>
            <label for="check">
                <i class="fas fa-bars menu-btn"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-times close-btn"></i>
            </label>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="info">
                <p style="color: white;">A student for QA studies at INT college, experienced in the fields of customer service and sound engineering. I have good interpersonal relations, always tends to look at the "big picture", and sustains high work ethics. Looking for a first chance to prove myself in the field of quality assurance, highly motivated to learn and evolve as much as I can.</p>
                <img src="תמונת פרופיל.jpg" width="106" height="69">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: So, you're asking a lot of separate questions here. Some are pretty basic and others more complex. I'd recommend you take it one step at a time and fix your problems in turn. Check the recommendations for asking questions here, and try to boil your problem down to the smallest amount of code you need to reproduce each problem. (This exercise by itself may lead you to a solution!) And, certainly, responsiveness is the last thing to worry about - you need to understand the basics before that will make any sense!

Comment: as @JohnP said, some are basic and some are complex. Try editing the css using dev tools to understand how html and css works for a start. 
As for point 2 - you have given a `max-width: 65px;` for `.content` which is basically pushing the text down. Increase it to make the text normal

Comment: @JohnP you're completely right, and since i'm new to all of these things, can i ask you to break it down for me? forget about the responsiveness - just the basic elements of the page i you please..

Comment: @akshithDayanand i tried what you said and changed the max width to 51000, and it's better! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

As in comments, breaking it down and only addressing the simpler points. A general point is that you're trying to do an awful lot in one jump here. If you're starting out, don't do an entire complex page first. Do a simple page, so you understand what's going on, then add a little more, then a little more. If you do this, you'll allow your understanding to grow rather than giving yourself a very large amount to understand from the start.

Your first question was why the h1, para and menu are all at the top of the page. This is because you've wrapped them in a `header` element that has `display: flex` defined. The default direction for `flex` is `row`, so each block within the `header` is treated as equal and laid out in a row.

If you want these laid out in "normal" fashion, remove the `display: flex` on `header`, or move these blocks outside the `header`.

Your second question is really several different questions. As noted in the comments, the problem with your `content` block is simply that you've specified a max-width of 65px. The browser's done exactly what you asked for - it's just that you didn't know what you were asking! The solution here is just to remove the `max-width` restriction. If you don't need it, don't set it.

We can't do much about the background picture - it's not shown in your snippet because the image file isn't present within StackOverflow. However, the usual cause of the image not being shown in this sort of situation is that the path you've specified is wrong. The `url` needs to be the exact path to the image, relative to the css file's location. If the page is on the web then the easiest solution is often to provide the fully qualified URL (i.e. `https://aaa.bbb.ccc/images/bg.jpg` or whatever). If you're working on your own computer, this won't work because the image doesn't have a full URL, and you'll need to work out the path yourself. Look at your directory structure and see whether you need to go "up" before you go "across" into a new directory.

The problem with the profile pic is again probably that the path is wrong.

I hope that gives you enough to get started.

Comment: That's amazing John thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem. If it's useful, please do accept the answer as correct. 

Comment: Sure, how can i do this?

Comment: Next to the answer, at the top left, there are upvote and downvote buttons, together with an "accept" button. Ta!